# specific arguments for geocoder in google

Tags: python-3.x, google-geocoder

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.google([self.getLatitude(), self.getLongitude()], method = 'reverse')
    return g.street + " " + g.housenumber + ", " + g.postal + " " + g.city + ", " + g.country
```

So I have this code and my problem is, that I can't find any arguments that specify my choosen language and the length of the country in the output. Eg. I have 'CH' and I'd like to have 'Switzerland'.

Comment: I just found out, that you can add language='en' after method :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will get GeoCoder to do that. But you can translate the code yourself.

```
$ pip install iso3166

>>> from iso3166 import countries
>>> countries.get("CH")
Country(name='Switzerland', alpha2='CH', alpha3='CHE', numeric='756', apolitical_name='Switzerland')
```